# Correct prepositions to use with "treat" and "hold"?

Tags: meaning, expressions, prepositions

Is the following conversation grammatically correct?

Both "treat" and "hold" use "to".

A: Do you cook yourself? What did you cook last?
B: I made salad, it's tasty, I will **treat you to** it later.
A: I will **hold you to** that.

Regarding the meaning, does "I will **hold you to** that" mean "**I'll really go to have(eat) that**"?

Comment: 'I'll treat you to some of it later' sounds more natural.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When someone says “I’ll hold you to that” they are implying they are going to take what you said seriously. In this case, the person is saying they do want some of the salad you prepared.

Edit: It’s less of the person saying “I really have to eat that now” and more of the person expecting your offer to be true. A lot of times we offer things out of generosity but the other person may not accept, so by saying “I’ll hold you to that” they are stating that they would like to accept what you offered.